# Name that camera

Tags: security

I have a few cameras around the house that were here before I bought the house. I believe I know which cables belong to them in the utility room, but I've plugged them into a DVR and there seems to be no signal. They are in places that are very high and hard to reach without a huge ladder, so this is the best shot I can get of them:
[image]

I had a roofer who was doing other work take a look and he said he couldn't find a model number or anything on them. Anyone have a clue what these are so I can read the manual, etc.?

Comment: We had something like this at place I worked at a few years ago. They model number was hidden under the plastic shroud which was accessed by removing the screws and sliding it off. Tried that??

Comment: Maybe they are decoys.  Or at least, after a few years in the weather, theyre decoys *now*...

Comment: I don't like that install.  If water drips down the cord, it could go into the connector.  There should be a dip in the wire so water drops off harmlessly.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a power cable.

Perhaps these are ethernet cameras which obtain power over ethernet (PoE). Try injecting PoE and put them on a network and see if they lease an IP address.